# In graph theory, are undirected graphs assumed to be reflexive? What are the assumptions about symmetry and transitivity?

Tags: graph-theory

The title says it all, please help me.In graph theory, are undirected graphs assumed to be reflexive? What are the assumptions about symmetry and transitivity?

Comment: What do you mean by reflexive in this context? These are properties of relations usually.

Comment: If the relation is "reachable" then yes, it is an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the author explicitly states otherwise, there are no assumptions — what you see is what you have. If $a\leftrightarrow b\leftrightarrow c$ are edges, and if there's an edge from $a$ to $c$, then it should be listed or shown explicitly, and similarly for loops $a\leftrightarrow a$. The same holds for directed graphs. Note, though, that an undirected graph, considered as a relation, is inherently symmetric.

Contrast this with Hasse diagrams of partially ordered sets, which attempt to depict a relation using as few edges as possible (if $a\to b\to c$ then $a\to c$ will *not* be shown, nor will edges $a\to a$ be shown). The Hasse diagram actually represents the strict version (irreflexive) of the *transitive reduction* of a relation.